# How to install NumPy using pipenv using piwheels?

Tags: python

Installing NumPy on a Raspberry Pi 3 takes forever because of compilation time.

I stumbled upon https://bennuttall.com/piwheels-building-a-faster-python-package-repository-for-raspberry-pi-users/.

Trying to avoid falling back to `pip3 install numpy --user`.

How can I install NumPy using pipenv using piwheels?

Comment: Which OS? IIRC pip on RPiOS is configured to use piwheels by default.`pip3 config list` should show if it's in the config

Comment: That's a very old post. If you're still using the hostedpi domain you should use piwheels.org instead (as Dirk said, pre-configured). See https://www.piwheels.org/